# Access variable returned from react function within render (in loop)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, class

I have a react class component, where I am passing list of module names and some other attributes. I tried to obtain module code by calling a function getModuleCode() and passing module name as a parameter.

```
class ModulesListing extends React.Component {
  getModuleCode(module){
       var moduleCode = 0;
       // Do relevant calls and get moduleCode
       return moduleCode;
    }
  render(){
    var {modulesList} = this.props;
    modulesList.forEach(module => {
        //here I need to call getModuleCode as getModuleCode(module.name)
       var moduleCode = getModuleCode(module.name)
       console.log(moduleCode)
    })

    return (
      //Info to display
    );
  }
}
```

If I tried as above mentioned, it prints as **undefined**
Also tried with setting as state, which is not suitable for looping. Here what I wanted is to get module code wrt certain module.

Comment: it should be `this.getModuleCode(...)`, if you are making api call inside `getModuleCode` then i think you need to check two thing, **1-** how to return the response of async call **2-** use of `promise.all`

Comment: Beside your problem why do you think setting a state is not suitable for looping? Actually lopping in render is not the best way to do something in React. Generally people use `.map` to do that. So, you can set a state for module list and map over it.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the codes in `componentDidMount` and in `componentDidUpdate` if the `modulesList` change, and store them in state.

**Example**

```js
function doCall() {
  return new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random().toString()), 1000)
  );
}

class ModulesListing extends React.Component {
  state = { codes: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getModuleCodes();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.modulesList !== prevProps.modulesList) {
      this.setState({ codes: [] }, this.getModuleCodes);
    }
  }

  getModuleCodes = () => {
    Promise.all(this.props.modulesList.map(doCall)).then(codes => {
      this.setState({ codes });
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { modulesList } = this.props;
    const { codes } = this.state;

    if (codes.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {modulesList.map((module, index) => (
          <div>
            {module}: {codes[index]}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ModulesListing modulesList={["a", "b", "c"]} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: can you explain, what has been done in doCall() function @Tholle

Comment: @usergs It's a function returning a promise simulating the `getModuleCode` function you talked about in your question.